# Determine what server side template an application is using

Tags: template-engine

I remember a server side template engine that renders `{{! anything}}` as `true`

I guess it renders like that because `anything` is an undefined variable. Not many template engines do that. For example, in mustache `{{! anything }}` is just a comment.

Other things get rendered as:

`{{ 1+1 }}` --> 2

`{{if 1==2}} yes {{else}} no {{end}}` --> no

It's not GO template.

I would like to use that template, but I can't remember the name. Does anyone know a template that does the same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be any templating syntax that uses `{{` - it depends on the implementation. If you use callbacks with the templating engine to retrieve a value or determine region visibility then you could use any double-brace engine, just process the `!` character in your callback code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a Tangular template: https://github.com/totaljs/Tangular

Tangular can be used with node.js as a server side template engine

Comment: Exactly the one I am looking for .. tnx!

Answer (score 0):

That looks a lot like Go's templates to me.

Apache Velocity has a slightly different style, but might offer you similar capabilities.

AngularJS also uses a double brace template style.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I have been looking for!

Comment: Oh, actually no it's not that template.. 
I have just tested and {{! anything }} returns `panic: template: t:1: unexpected "!" in command`